# Finding an orthogonal Matrix with distinct eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices

The symmetric matrix $A$ below has distinct eigenvalues 12, −6 and −12. Find an orthogonal matrix $P$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $P^TAP=D$. Use the square root symbol '$\sqrt\cdot$' where needed to give an exact value for your answer. 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -5 & -8\\
-5 & -1 & 8\\
-8 & 8 & -4
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
I know how to find matrix $D$ but im not sure how to find matrix $P$.

Answer (score 0):

The columns of P are the normalized eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalues of A, in the same order that you list the eigenvalues of A in the matrix D.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix for more information

Comment: One should add that the eigenvectors should be normalized.